# Drupal 8 access_permission breaking Blockview

Tags: caching, drupal, permissions

I have a problem with my Drupal 8 Installation.

I use content_access to have a role based access permission system per node. When a user with insufficient permissions accesses a node (e.g. putting in direct link /node/123) the block in the sidebar region which renders my menu down from Level 2, the whole block disappears for all user.

After editing the node in question and saving, everything is fine again. Also we checked which cache to clear and it seems it is fixed after clearing the Cache via Admin Toolbar -> D8 Symbol -> Flush all caches -> "Flush routing and link cache".

Before the bug occurs, watchdog mentions this:
`23/Aug 11:58  warning   access denied       /de/executive-boards`
and then the block disappears until fixed like the steps I took before.

What we already tried:

- Deactivating the Cache for the Block via preprocess.
- Adding `route` to #cache.contexts array.
- Drupal Cache in Admin Toolbar -> Configuration -> Performance is also disabled.

How can catch this error before happening? I'm relatively new to Drupal 8 and I don't even know where to start over again.

Specs:

- Drupal ~8.5
- content_access  8.x-1.0-alpha1